# Can only install Windows 7 in UEFI-Legacy Mode

Tags: windows, boot, bios, uefi, gpt

I have had an issue installing Windows 7 on an MSI system (FM2-A75IA-E53) in full UEFI mode which seams to be the same problem many have had without a solution. From everything I have read, this Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit OEM DVD has the needed EFI files to boot and install in this mode. However. after the files load and windows starts up the system always freezes right at the end of the red, blue, yellow, green graghic that forms the MS logo comes together just an instant before the display would normally go black for a second or two before you get the first install page to choose your language.

This system doesn't have a well defined UEFI setting in the setup. It says 'Windows 8 Compatibility' You either enable or disable it. Even though MSI does not have any good documentation on this MB detup feature, the consensus is amoung most that 'Enabled' is UEFI mode and sidabled is UEFI-Legacy or CSM mode. I had to 'Disable' this setting in order to get Windows installed. I was wanting to install in UEFI and upgrade it to Windows 10.

Do I need the UEFI mode? Does UEFI-Legacy or this CSM Mode install Windows 7 and Windows 10 in UEFI by default on a GPT disk? In other words, Does installing a Windows 7 or above OS on a UEFI machine in UEFI-Legacy or CSM mode automatically install an OS in Full UEFI mode on a GPT disk? Or does a Windows 7 install default to MBR emulation in UEFI-Legacy mode? Is there any standard practice for a system UEFI-Legacy mode to try to check drive and install system compatibility and install UEFI as a defualt.

It does have an EFI partition but no MSP (MS System Reserved) partition.

If I ultimately want a UEFI installed system, is it possible to install this UEFI or to change the type of system to UEFI afterward?

Answer (score -1):

You must have a Windows 7 x64 retail disk, as 64-bit is the only version of Windows which supports UEFI. There is also no specific OEM ISO, only the retail version which can be licensed/activated using the OEM serial + SLIC method.

So if you want to install Windows in BIOS mode due to some compatibility issues, you should change your BIOS/Firmware settings to disable UEFI or enable CSM or whatever options you BIOS has.

However, some more modern machines no longer support disabling UEFI. If this is the case, it sounds to me like you are trying to install Windows 7 using a USB flash drive? Installing Windows 7 using a flash drive is actually NOT officially supported and there are machines which exist that cannot install Windows 7 using USB drives at all, although some manage OK.

Therefore, have you tried burning the ISO to DVD and using that to install Windows?

Comment: `Installing Windows 7 using a flash drive is actually NOT officially supported.` I don't think so. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

Comment: Yes, I know MS does officially supports using a USB otherwise why would they recommend it. You also do NOT need a retail disk. OEM disks are for new builds and they are also used on UEFI systems. That suggest OFFICIAL support. For the record, This dvd is Windows 7 Ultimate OEM 64bit so for all of those pointing out the obvious about it needing to be 64 bit we are way past that. I edited the question. didn't think I needed to put that much detail in it.

Comment: You dont need UEFI mode, you can install W7 in BIOS mode then update to W10.

Comment: UEFI firmware has a separate CSM module, but there are only two boot (and installation) modes for Windows 7/8/10 64-bit => (UEFI+GPT) or (BIOS[=CSM]+MBR).  If destination disk is GPT style and you boot source USB/DVD the UEFI way there should be no problems installing Windows.

Comment: @snayob I installed this Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit OEM dvd disk using "Windows 8 Compatibility" - Disabled. I am assuming that this was CSM mode or module even though the system setup doed not spell out 'Compatibility Support Module' or its acronym 'CSM'? What it sounds like you are saying is that if it is in CSM mode then it will always install everything with an MBR? Then why did the install create an EFI partition? Or is this strictly an UEFI MB and there is no CSM mode?

Comment: Its not *officially* supported, but there's ways to do it, like with rufus. The windows usb tool only really started being supported with windows 8. Dosen't mean it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Rich Manson - if you boot installation DVD(or USB) in UEFI mode then destination is expected to be GPT disk for installation. And you boot DVD/USB the BIOS/CSM way then installation destination is expected to be MBR disk. Windows knows only UEFI+GPT (or BIOS+MBR). Other combinations lead to boot/installation problems.

Comment: @snayob We know this already and I mention I think twice, for emphasis, but I'll do it a third time. I was booting Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit OEM dvd to a UEFI boot installation with a destination GPT HDD but the dvd would not go into setup.

Comment: @Rich, when you know "this" already, then there is a small additional note for Windows 7 like - "you have to enable CSM" to be able to boot PE(recovery, boot.wim), BUT boot UEFI way! This is what I did on a Dell laptop.

Comment: I would also suggest using dism.exe for installation and manual partitioning of hard disk (with script - there is a Microsoft guide how to do this). So you don't need to bother UEFI, MBR, GPT and so on. The final step is using bcdboot.exe for writing boot related files.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7 doesn't support the new UEFI GOP (Graphics Output Protocol) and [requires VGA option ROM (BIOS interrupt 10 (INT 10H)) to boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2828074/windows-7-setup-hangs-at-starting-windows-on-surface-pro).

To enable successful Windows 7 EFI boot you must enable CSM (compatibility support mode). (Dell BIOS calls this "Enable Legacy Option ROMs").

Only Windows 8 / 8.1 / 10 can boot in pure UEFI mode.

The partitioning scheme does not change when utilizing CSM, it's still GPT with an EFI partition.