# Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit cannot boot in UEFI

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, uefi

I noticed that in Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit image there **exist** `bootmgr.efi` and `winload.efi` and I applied it to my computer. Then I edited my BCD to add an option to boot it. When attempting to boit in UEFI mode, Windows 7 always gets stuck at `disk.sys` and shuts down automatically. However there's nothing wrong when booting in legacy mode (boot `winload.exe` instead of efi). How exactly can I boot that Windows 7 in UEFI?
My computer originally had Windows 8.1 installed on it out-of-the-box and I turned boot mode to "UEFI with CSM" in BIOS settings.

Edit: Problem solved. My solution is to first boot into Win7 under LEGACY mode, install chipset driver (pre-downloaded from [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26984/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-?product=78930)) and then switch back to UEFI-CSM. Now Windows 7 no longer crashes at `disk.sys`.
But can anyone explain why it's related to chipset driver???

Comment: Are you booting from Windows 7 64 DVD/USB or you already have Windows 7 64 installed on your system and now it's not booting? Are you aware what type of Disk Partitioning scheme exists for your hard drive, is it MBR or GPT? Windows 7 shall boot in UEFI mode with GPT partition scheme  Hard drive.

Comment: It's GPT and the boot partition is an EFI System Partition. The BCD was originally created by Windows 10 (stock 8.1 got formatted). I only applied the Windows 7 image to another partition on my hard drive and added an entry for it with Bootice. I have a secondary drive that's MBR so I am able to create an alternative boot record using `bcdboot.exe` and then comes the question.

Comment: Could you link this chipset driver?